# Changing XML to Cakephp friendly array with DOMXPath php

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, xpath

Is there a way we can transform XML to Cakephp friendly array without using too many queries in DOMXpath in php?

Below is what I've got but I can't seem t access attributes and getAttributes function gives me an error.

```
$dom = new DomDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-1");
        $dom->load($xmlUrl);
        $array = new DomXPath($dom);

        $state = $array->query("//month/state");
        $dwelling_type = $array->query("//dwelling_type[@code]");
        $typical_value = $array->query("//dwelling_type/typical_value");
        $dom = $array->query("//dwelling_type/dom");
        $discount = $array->query("//dwelling_type/discount");
        $acr = $array->query("//dwelling_type/acr");
        $renters = $array->query("//dwelling_type/renters");
        $vacancy = $array->query("//dwelling_type/vacancy");
        $yield = $array->query("//dwelling_type/yield");
        $som = $array->query("//dwelling_type/som");
        $search_dsr = $array->query("//dwelling_type/search_dsr");
        $dsr = $array->query("//dwelling_type/dsr");
        $sr = $array->query("//dwelling_type/sr");

        //$array = Xml::toArray($array);

        for($i=0;$i<$typical_value->length;$i++){

            //$state = $dsr_data->getElementsByTagName('state');

            $dsr_stats[$i] = array(
                //'state' => $state->item($i)->getAttribute('code'),
                'dwelling_type' => $dwelling_type->item($i)->getAttribute('code'),
                'typical_value' => $typical_value->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'dom' => $dom->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'discount' => $discount->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'acr' => $acr->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'renters' => $renters->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'vacancy' => $vacancy->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'yield' => $yield->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'som' => $som->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'search_dsr' => $search_dsr->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'dsr' => $dsr->item($i)->nodeValue,
                'sr' => $sr->item($i)->nodeValue
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I read xml into array-like structures using [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) php function